# SharePoint 2010 Broken links report

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

How to find broken links in SharePoint  2010 Site collection without using SharePoint Designer?

Comment: did the below reply works for you?

Answer (score 2):

One method is using the SharePoint designer. But if you dont want use it then other alternates are.

- [SharePoint 2010 SEO Analysis with the IIS SEO Toolkit](http://tristanwatkins.com/sharepoint-2010-seo-analysis-with-the-iis-seo-toolkit/)
- Use the 3rd party tool [SharePoint Broken Link Manager Lite (FREE)](https://store.qipoint.com/product-p/sp14-00-links.htm), it is free.